# Good short and freely downloadable STL tutorial

Tags: c++, stl

I want to refresh my STL knowledge before interview. Could anyone recommend good short and freely downloadable STL tutorial? Thank you.

EDIT:  Preferably in PDF.

Answer (score 7):

Its not a book and for free download, but Scott Myers [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) in combination with a good STL reference is in my opinion invaluable for an interview preparation.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

These are two very good sites for STL reference. For interview I would suggest to refer **good** book [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260) by Nicolai M. Josuttis .

Answer (score 1):

[STL Pocket Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005566/) from O'Reilly :

> Programmers familiar with the Standard
>   Template Library need a small,
>   lightweight memory-aid. That's what
>   the STL Pocket Reference is. It's
>   small, lightweight, and chock-full of
>   information that you can take in at a
>   glance, so you can get on with your
>   work.

ACCU [review](http://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=1706) is: Recommended.

You can download it as PDF for $7.99

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/noframes.html) is the most tutorial-like downloadable material on STL I know of.  It's a pile of HTML files, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just started picking this up a couple of months ago, I found this website the most useful:

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/start

Another useful site, especially when I wanted more detail:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

And a couple of people have linked to sgi here, there's a .zip downloadable version of that -- it's not very short, quick, or handy, because essentially you're downloading the site as an archive of html files, but once you get the hang of the containers and algorithms, this is a complete reference for which you don't need the internet.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html

***All three are free.**